# Is there any way to plot geom_smooth + geom_ribbon?

Tags: python, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

I am new to python and I am using the same code from this post:
[In ggplot2,specify values to use for geom_smooth() confidence interval (similar to geom_errorbar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72563586/in-ggplot2-specify-values-to-use-for-geom-smooth-confidence-interval-similar/72563677#72563677)
to plot the graph in r

I tried to replicate the result in python:

```py
g = so.Plot(x = risk_cont["day"], 
            y = risk_cont["mean"],
            ymin = risk_cont['conf.low'],
            ymax = risk_cont['conf.high'] ).add(so.Line())
```

However, the plot did not interpolate the interval between the given data. Is there anyway to do it in python with only `seaborn + seaborn.objects`?

Comment: [Why doesn't the seaborn plot show a confidence interval / error bars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59127738/why-doesnt-the-seaborn-plot-show-a-confidence-interval-error-bars#:~:text=There%20is%20probably,interval%20to%20plot.)